# Change abstract title font in scrartcl/KOMA

Tags: fonts, koma-script, abstract

I want to change the typeface of the `abstract` heading in `scrartcl`.

`latexdef` tells me that in my case (no `titlepage`, no `twocolumn`), `\sectfont` is used:

```latex
> latexdef -c scrartcl -s abstract
...
\begin{center}
  {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname
    \vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
\end{center}
...
```

So I tried setting it with the regular `\setkomafont`:

```latex
\documentclass[abstract = true]{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{section}{\centering\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}% this heading should be in the same style as the section title below
  Text
\end{abstract}

\section{Section Title}% for comparison

\end{document}
```

However, the typeface for the abstract heading is not changed at all.

I am unsure as to whether this is the expected behavior or a bug and whether or not I need to use a different command to set the abstract heading font, especially since:

```latex
> latexdef -c scrartcl -s abstract
...
\if@twocolumn\if@abstrt
    \addsec*{\abstractname}
  \fi
...
```

This time (`\documentclass[abstract = true, twocolumn]{scrartcl}`) , the abstract heading font is indeed changed.

Admittedly, it is possible to change the font globally via `\setkomafont{disposition}` and then reset it after `abstract` has been called, however, this seems a very inelegant solution to me.

What better options do I have?

Comment: Why not just change `\setkomafont{section}` to `\setkomafont{sectioning}` (or equivalently, `deposition`)? This will change the font of all sectioning titles, including the abstract's.

Comment: I thought there was a way to change it separately, I have now opted to use `\setkomafont{disposition}` and then set the other sectioning levels to whatever I need afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `abstract=true` enables the automatic heading of the abstract. So if you want to use an own abstract heading, remove option `abstract=true`. Then you can use eg. `\addsec*{\abstractname}`:

```latex
\documentclass[
   %abstract=true% <- remove this option, if there should be no automatic heading in the abstract
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}% \centering is no font command!

\begin{document}
\addsec*{\abstractname}
\begin{abstract}
  \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\section{Section Title}% for comparison
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off topic: `\centering` is not a font command. Therefore it is not recommended to use `\centering` for a font element.

Answer (score 1):

From what you see in the `scrartcl.cls` file, the `abstract` environment uses the `\sectfont` command to format the "Abstract" title in one column document:

```
    \begin{center}
      {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname
        \vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}
```

We could redefine this command, but this would also affect other commands that use it (e.g. `\titlefont`). For these reasons the simplest way, in my opinion is this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{\def\sectfont{\normalsize\itshape}}
```

A second, not so elegant solution, could be this one:

```
\renewcommand*{\abstractname}{\normalsize\rmfamily\itshape\mdseries Abstract}
```

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[abstract = true]{scrartcl}
  \setkomafont{section}{\centering\normalfont\itshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{\def\sectfont{\normalsize\itshape}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{abstract}% this heading should be in the same style as the section title below
  Text of the abstract text of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract of the abstract 
\end{abstract}
 \section{Section Title}% for comparison
\end{document}
```

[image]